# Drag & drop objects between Angular components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dragula, angular-dragula

I'm using the Dragula module with Angular 4, and I want to drag a div from a side-panel into the main view. However, these two areas of the screen are in seperate ng modules, and seperate components.

I am assuming these two areas are ignorant of each other due to virtual/shadow doms, so is there any way for me to implement Dragula across different components, or am I simply going to have to refactor the whole app?

Comment: Can you create plunker?